# place a new TikZ node behind others

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to have a new TikZ node appear behind the previous one. For instance in beamer presentations for highlighting parts of code.

I can do this if I place the `\node` *before* the new node and give it a hardcoded overlay number, but I'd rather keep the `<+>` overlay specification.

Of course any suggestions for a better way to do this are also welcome!

An example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,fancyvrb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw<2->[fill=blue!50] (-0.5\linewidth,-1em) rectangle (0.5\linewidth,1em);

    \node {
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{Verbatim}
Please note this line!
\end{Verbatim}
      \end{minipage}
    };

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: example for using layers

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,fancyvrb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node<+-> at (0,0){
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \VerbatimInput{queries/example.xquery}
      \end{minipage}
    };

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \draw<+->[fill=blue!50] (-0.5\linewidth,-1em) rectangle (0.5\linewidth,1em);
    \end{pgfonlayer}

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways that I know of:

1. Use PGF layers
2. Use offsets in your incremental overlay specifications.

Here is an example with both.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,fancyvrb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{using pgflayers}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{box}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{text}
  \pgfsetlayers{box,text}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (-0.5\linewidth,-1em) rectangle (0.5\linewidth,1em);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{text}
    \node<+->{
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
%\begin{Verbatim}
Please note this line!
%\end{Verbatim}
      \end{minipage}
    };
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{box}
    \draw<+->[fill=blue!50] (-0.5\linewidth,-1em) rectangle (0.5\linewidth,1em);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{using offsets}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (-0.5\linewidth,-1em) rectangle (0.5\linewidth,1em);
    \draw<.(2)->[fill=blue!50] (-0.5\linewidth,-1em) rectangle (0.5\linewidth,1em);
    \node<+->{
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
%\begin{Verbatim}
Please note this line!
%\end{Verbatim}
      \end{minipage}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I couldn't get the `Verbatim` environment to work; do you really need it?

Comment: Layers should do nicely. Thanks for the tip, I had missed it in the manual so far.  I'll give it a try now.

Comment: I like the verbatim to display code, but I could use semiverbatim or listings if it makes a difference. I tried with the layers and works:

Comment: listings probably works better for displaying code.