# Tikz: Saving text/content from node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why is this not working and what can I do to get it to work?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\newcommand{\lastsave}{defaulttext}
\newcommand{\save}[1]{\def\lastsave{#1}#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\save{text}};
\node at (0,-1) {\lastsave};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Afterall, it does work outside of tikz:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\newcommand{\lastsave}{defaulttext}
\newcommand{\save}[1]{\def\lastsave{#1}#1}

\begin{document}
\save{text}

\lastsave    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\gdef` instead `\def` : `\newcommand{\save}[1]{\gdef\lastsave{#1}#1}`. So the new definition of `\lastsave` is valid outside the current group too.

Comment: @esdd: Also: Could you explain what this group-thing is? Do don't mean an environment or something like that, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `\node` sets the node text inside a group you have to use `\gdef` instead `\def`. Then your redefinition is global:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\newcommand{\lastsave}{defaulttext}
\newcommand{\save}[1]{\gdef\lastsave{#1}#1}% <- changed
\begin{document}
\save{text}
\lastsave
\end{document}
```

---

With `\def` your redefinition is valid only in the current group. In your second example there in no additional group inside the document. So you get what you want. But if you set `\save` inside a group, that means `{\save{...}}` or `\begingroup\save{...}\endgroup` or `\bgroup\save{...}\egroup`, then your redefinition is limited by this group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\lastsave}{defaulttext}
\newcommand{\save}[1]{\def\lastsave{#1}\lastsave}

\begin{document}
\save{first text} stores the text -- \lastsave

\bigskip

But using the command inside a group like

\bigskip
{\save{second text}},
\begingroup \save{third text}\endgroup,
\bgroup\save{fourth text}\egroup,

\begin{center}
  \save{last text}
\end{center}

you still get -- \lastsave{} -- outside the groups.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are environments and commands groups as well?

Comment: Yes, environments are groups. If you use something like `\textbf{\save{text}}` the `\save` command is also in a group.